# Problema al subir imágenes en Laravel

Tags: laravel, fileupload, livewire

Estoy realizando una carga múltiples de imágenes y a veces funciona bien y otra se cuelga, otras veces no toma determinadas imágenes y me redirecciona a la página 404. Quisiera si me pueden brindar una mano. Agradezco mucho toda intención.

Estoy utilizando Livewire de la siguiente manera:

```
<input wire:model="imagenes" type="file" name="imagenes" class="form-control-file" multiple>
```

Una vez seleccionadas las imágenes pasa por el validador:

```
$this->validate([
    'imagenes.*' => 'image|max:2048',
]);
```

Y para guardar las imágenes estoy utilizando la siguiente metodología

```
foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGaleria) {
         $imgUrl = $pathGaleria->store('imagenesPropiedades');

         $img = imgPropiedades::create([
               'url' => $imgUrl,
               'property_id' => $this->propiedadId
         ]);
}
```

En el filesystem:

```
'imagenesPropiedades' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Recibo este error en consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pueden brindar una sugerencia para mejorar esta carga por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que como uso livewire en tiempo real no había contemplado la etiqueta enctype="multipart/form-data" además tuve que ampliar los espacios del servidor max_upload. Muchas gracias